# in function parameter why (i++) got some error while (i+1) is running

Tags: c++

Case 1:when i put i++ at function parameter at that time i got blank output

Case 2: when i put i+1 rather than i++ at that time i got correct output

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 
int foccurance(int arr[], int n, int i, int key)
{
    if (arr[i] == key)
    {
        return i;
    }
    if (i == n)
    {
        return -1;
    }
  ///here rather than i++ if i put i+1 then it runs properly
    return foccurance(arr, n, i++, key);
}

int main()
{
    int ar[] = {2, 5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int n = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int);
    int k;

    cout << "key val=" << endl;
    cin >> k;

    int ind = foccurance(ar, n, 0, k);
    cout << "your value is at index=" << ind;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i++` and `i+1` evaluate to different values. Why not print `i` inside the function to see the value? (or preferably use a debugger to inspect the values in each function call.)

Comment: Also move `if (i == n)` before `if (arr[i] == key)`. Otherwise it will cause invalid memory access

Comment: With `i++` it's not only a blank output - but an infinite recursion which blocks your program from advancing forever, because you pass 0 every time

Comment: i believe post and preincrement are the most overrated operators. When you want to pass the value that is one greater than `i` to the function then there is nothing wrong with `i+1`

Comment: If you must write this trivial search recursively **and** you must increment `i` rather than simply using `i + 1`, the recursive call should use `++i` and not `i++`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expressions `i++` and `i+1` evaluate to different things and after the operations, `i` will hold different values.

```
void f(int v)
{
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

int i = 0;
f(i+1); // Prints 1
std::cout << i << std::endl; // Prints 0
f(i++); // Prints 0
std::cout << i << std::endl; // Prints 1.
```

So `i+1`

- will not modify `i`, but
- it will evaluate to a value that is 1 larger than `i`.

On the other hand, `i++`

- will modify `i` and set it to `i+1`,
- but it will evaluate to the original value of `i` before adding 1 to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `++i` or `i+1` in place of `i++`, this is because: basically `++i` returns the value after it is incremented, while `i++` returns the value before it is incremented.

`i++` --> "assigns" --> increments.

`++i` --> increments --> "assigns".

so as per your program, `0` is passed every time, hence it becomes infinite recursion and program does not proceeds.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pre-increment operator like `++i`

`i++` means `i = i + 1` and it is a post increment operator.

So when you pass i++ in function parameter it pass it's previous value and then increment by 1.

So always the value of i is 0.But the pre increment operator increment the value first, then pass it's value to the function argument.

You have to write code like that:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int foccurrence(int arr[], int n, int i, int key)
    {
        if (arr[i] == key)
        {
            return i;
        }

        if (i == n)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return foccurrence(arr, n, ++i, key);
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        int ar[] = {2, 5, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7};
        int n = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int);
        int k;
    
        cout << "key val=" << endl;
        cin >> k;
    
        int ind = foccurrence(ar, n, 0, k);
        cout << "your value is at index=" << ind;
        return 0;
    }
```